glsl rendering of shadows with shadowmapping
so i would like to add shadows to my rendering program,
I am using python (with moderngl) and glsl, but the shadows aren't rendering...
Without using arrays it works fine but i need to use them (later on i will try to add more lights).
So the program doesn't return any error, but there isn't any shadow
Here is my vert shader (shadowCoord are the coordinate of the shadow points i use in the frag shader and m_view_l are all the light matrices for now i only use one : so number_mat = 1)
#version 410
#define MAX_SIZE 6

//in
layout (location = 0) in vec2 in_texcoord;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 in_position;
layout (location = 2) in vec3 in_normales;

//out
out vec2 uv_0;
out vec3 v_pos;
out vec3 v_normals;
out float rd_light_diffraction;
out vec2 pixel_pos;
out vec4 shadowCoord[MAX_SIZE];

//matrices
uniform mat4 m_proj;
uniform mat4 m_view;

uniform mat4 m_view_l[MAX_SIZE];
uniform int number_mat;
uniform mat4 m_proj_l;
uniform mat4 m_model;

uniform mat4 m_bias = mat4(
0.5,0.0,0.0,0.0,
0.0,0.5,0.0,0.0,
0.0,0.0,0.5,0.0,
0.5,0.5,0.5,1.0
);

float random(vec2 st){
    return fract(sin(dot(st.xy, vec2(12.9898,78.233))) * 43758.5453123);
}

void main(){

    uv_0 = vec2(1.0-in_texcoord);
    gl_Position = m_proj*m_view*m_model*vec4(in_position, 1.0);//vector4 for vertex pos
    pixel_pos = vec2(gl_Position);

    //depth textures
    for (int i = 0; i<number_mat; i++){
        mat4 shadowMVP = m_proj_l*m_view_l[i]*m_model;
        shadowCoord[i] = m_bias*shadowMVP*vec4(in_position,1.0);
        shadowCoord[i].z-=0.005;
    }

    //lighting
    v_pos = vec3(m_model*vec4(in_position, 1.0)); 
    v_normals = normalize(mat3(transpose(inverse(m_model)))*normalize(in_normales));//vector4 for the normal of the vertices
    rd_light_diffraction = random(vec2(in_texcoord.x*22+41, in_texcoord.y*43+63)); 
}

Then  the frag shader with shadowMap an array of depth texture used for the shadows in the getShadow function
#version 410
#define MAX_SIZE 6

layout (location = 0) in vec2 uv_0;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 v_pos;
layout (location = 2) in vec3 v_normals;
layout (location = 3) in float rd_light_diffraction;
layout (location = 4) in vec2 pixel_pos;
in vec4 shadowCoord[MAX_SIZE];

out vec4 fragColor;


uniform vec3 cam_pos;

uniform sampler2D u_texture_0;
uniform sampler2DShadow shadowMap[MAX_SIZE];
uniform int number_mat;

//matrices
uniform mat4 m_proj;
uniform mat4 m_view;
uniform mat4 m_model;

uniform vec3 light_pos[20]; //max number of lights is 10
uniform vec3 light_color[20];
uniform float light_intensity[20];


//light params
float AMBIANT_LIGHT = 0.06;
float STRENGTH_DIFFUSE = 13.0; //the diffuse has more impact


float getShadow(){
    float shadow = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<number_mat; i++){
        shadow += textureProj(shadowMap[i], shadowCoord[i]);
    }
    return shadow/number_mat;
}

void main(){
    //lighting
    vec3 TOTAL_SHADING_COLOR = vec3(0.0);
    float DIFFUSE_LIGHT = 0.0;
    float SPECULAR_LIGHT = 0.0;

    vec3 v_cam = normalize(cam_pos-v_pos); //vector3 for the cam vector

    //we iterate through all the lights in the scene (20 max for performance issues)
    int iteration = 0;
    while (iteration<20 && light_intensity[iteration]!=0) {
        //base color light
        float r_col = light_color[iteration].r/255;
        float g_col = light_color[iteration].g/255;
        float b_col = light_color[iteration].b/255;
        vec3 shade = vec3(r_col,g_col,b_col);
        float d_light = sqrt(pow((light_pos[iteration].x-v_pos.x),2)+pow((light_pos[iteration].y-v_pos.y),2)+pow((light_pos[iteration].z-v_pos.z),2));

        //we calculate the diffuse strength (basic intensity based on dot product)
        vec3 v_vector_light = normalize(light_pos[iteration]-v_pos);
        if (dot(v_vector_light,v_normals)>0.002){ //don't add negative lighting
            DIFFUSE_LIGHT += (1/(rd_light_diffraction+(d_light)*4)); //shading based on the distance and a small number
            DIFFUSE_LIGHT *= light_intensity[iteration]*dot(v_vector_light,v_normals); //multiplied by the light intensity and angle

            //specular touch (based on the angle with the light)
            vec3 v_reflect_light = reflect(-(v_vector_light), v_normals);
            if (dot(v_reflect_light,v_cam)>0){
                SPECULAR_LIGHT = pow(dot(v_reflect_light,v_cam), 70); //multiplied to get a specular highlight
            }
            float shadow = getShadow();

            TOTAL_SHADING_COLOR += (shade*((DIFFUSE_LIGHT*STRENGTH_DIFFUSE)+SPECULAR_LIGHT))*(shadow);
        }

        iteration+=1;
    }
    vec3 shading = TOTAL_SHADING_COLOR + vec3(1,1,1)*AMBIANT_LIGHT;
    

    //converting it to color with 255 as max
    vec3 raw_color = texture(u_texture_0, uv_0).rgb;
    float r = raw_color.r/255;
    float g = raw_color.g/255;
    float b = raw_color.b/255;
    vec3 color = vec3(r*shading.r,g*shading.g,b*shading.b)*255;
    
    //gamma correction
    float gamma = 2.2;
    color=pow(color, vec3(gamma));
    color=pow(color, vec3(1/gamma));


    fragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
}

and finally how i set the values for the shadows when initialised (the rest worked fine)
        self.shader_program['shadowMap'] = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
        self.shader_program['number_mat'] = 1
        m_view = np.array([self.app.lights[0].m_view_l for _ in range(6)], dtype = np.float32)

        #depth texture
        self.depth_texture.use(location=1)
        
        self.shadow_program['m_view_l'].write(self.app.lights[0].m_view_l)
        self.shader_program['m_view_l'].write(m_view.tobytes())

and for the update shadow part (the m_view is an array of the same view matrice (i didn't find an another way to do it)):
        m_view = np.array([self.app.lights[0].m_view_l for _ in range(6)], dtype = np.float32)
        self.shader_program['m_view_l'].write(m_view.tobytes())

So if you have an idea of why this doesn't work i would be more than happy to hear it XD
Have a great day!
